# Why is the sign of work different in physics and chemistry in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is the sign convention of work opposite in physics and chemistry? This only makes matters more complicated. Why did the scientists have to do this? Is there even any reason behind this?
[image: Sign Convention]

Comment: Get used to it.  This is just one example of many.  Some scientists consider tensile stress as positive and some consider compressive stress as positive, for example.

Comment: "Why did the scientists have to do this?" You made my day, thanks. I think it's not much of a generalization to say that in science conventions are constantly there to make your day hard, whichever field you work on. You'd hope there would be a striving effort to standardize these choices universally, but then you go to the literature and often find the opposite. Unfortunately, such is life.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/why-do-chemistry-and-physics-have-different-sign-convention-in-thermodynamics#:~:text=In%20physics%20class%2C%20we%20write,work%20done%20on%20the%20system.

Comment: OK @secavara, you can have your way.  Whichever choice you like best, we in other disciplines have decided to standardize for everyone on the other choice.  How does that make you feel?

Comment: The shown convention for physics is not really consistent. In thermodynamics and mechanics you might see it differently. Personally I like the intuitive idea of "positive energy is added energy", so that work done *on* a system (providing more energy to the system) is positive. But it really doeneds on the typical usage in various fields of science and engineering.

Comment: Why do physicists use $\textbf{i}$ and EEs use $\textbf{j}$ ?  Why is current direction the reverse of electron flow?  and so on

Comment: @ChetMiller Honestly, it'd be great. I could finally share results effectively and swiftly with scientists and engineers everywhere.

Comment: So @Steeven, if "positive energy is added energy," in expansion, since work done on the system is negative, how does that fit in with your scheme of things?

Comment: @secavara, not everyone would feel the same way.  The subsurface geophysicists and bioscience people are comfortable with compressive stress being positive, while engineers and most physicists are comfortable with tensile stress being positive.  Both groups believe that their way is the only way that makes sense, and neither group would be willing to change.  I know I wouldn't (even though I've worked in both areas).

Comment: @ChetMiller It sure does. As you said, then work done on the system is negative.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of convention in a specific community, which typically arose by accident, like many other things. Just to give a few examples:

- writing the complex exponent $e^{\pm i\omega t}$
- where to keep $2\pi$ in Fourier transform
- whether one rotates the coordinate system or whether one rotates in rotation transformations

It is by far more complicated for many people to agree to use the same notations, conventions, definitions.